# Check if the file respects the schema when loading a spark df

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I am manually defining a schema for a df that I load:

```
my_schema= StructType([ \
    StructField("foo",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("bar",StringType(),True)
  ])

df = spark.read\
  .schema(my_schema)\
  .option("multiline", True)\
  .json('my_path')
```

It there a way to make sure that this file complies with the schema before loading it? I don't want to load the file if there are unmatched columns. I'm trying to avoid to load the df to perform this check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's not possible by `"pure"` Spark API.

Using Spark API you can read input file with specific schema and limit to `1` row (for instance) and than run your schema validation step:

```
df = spark.read \
  .schema(my_schema) \
  .option("multiline", True) \
  .json('my_path') \
  .limit(1)
```